# PowerShell ignore profile script when calling another script

Tags: powershell, scripting, profile

this is racking my brain. I have a profile script that I use to prep my system, it works great. Now the problem is, the system I am working on is managed by a company and they are pushing scripts for system validations and remediation like a normal company would do, however, what ever tool they are using to do it it not calling the -noprofile command in PowerShell. So what I'm finding is that every time they call a script under my user context, its runs my `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` first....which can be really annoying. I have not contacted the service desk to say "hey can you change your processes because it making my system do this...?"

Is there a way I can write in my profile script something like this:

```
If($MyInvocation.MyCommand.ToString() -ne 'Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'){
    Break
}
```

I'm finding this does not work. if the PowerShell command is called:

```
powershell -file d:\Scripts\testscript.ps1
```

How do I get detect the file name call from the profile script. I can detect it in a testscript.ps1 using any of these variables:

```
'$MyInvocation.InvocationName:' + $MyInvocation.InvocationName
'$MyInvocation.MyCommand: ' + $MyInvocation.MyCommand
'$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name: ' + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
'$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path: ' + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
'$PSCommandPath: ' + $PSCommandPath
'$PSScriptRoot :' + $PSScriptRoot
```

Am I asking the impossible?

Comment: You could use `Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $PID" |% ParentProcessId` to extract the pid of the parent process, then inspect if it's the tool in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to distinguish in your `$PROFILE` file is to test if any arguments were passed to the PowerShell executable on startup:

```
if ([Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs().Count -gt 1) { exit }
```

<sup>Note: There's always at least *one* argument, namely the *executable* itself.</sup>

If there's a chance that even your *interactive* sessions are started with arguments, you'd have to examine the [`[Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs) array more specifically.